# Need to wait unitl get the server time to start crafting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a craft system that uses playfab server time to calculate when will finish the craft.

This is how I get the server time:

```
 public void GetServerTime()
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetTime(new GetTimeRequest(), (GetTimeResult result) =>
    {          
        DateTime now = result.Time.AddHours(1); // GMT+1
        serverTime = Utilities.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(now);  // in seconds          
    }, null);
}
```

On click the Start Craft Button I have this code:

```
public void StartCraft(double craftTime)
{
    playFab.GetServerTime(); //server time variable updates
    double endTime = serverTime + craftTime;   
    StartCrafting(craftTime); // coroutine
}
```

After the coroutine ends I want to check if the server time is >= to the end time (this way should also avoid cheating).

The problem is that when I get the server time it takes some time to update the serverTime variable and the code continues executing, thats why the endTime is wrong. I want something like this:

```
 double endTime = GetServerTime() + craftTime;
```

But I dont know how to make a function to return the value directly. It says that i cant return a value because that function is void. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I don't know how your method works exactly so guessing a bit here)

`GetServerTime` seems to be asynchronous meaning you have to wait until you get a value back. So you can't directly return a value.

But you could add a Callback instead which is executed as soon as a value is available. You can than remove the variable `serverTime`.

```
public void GetServerTime(Action<double> callback)
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetTime(new GetTimeRequest(), (GetTimeResult result) =>
    {          
        DateTime now = result.Time.AddHours(1); // GMT+1

        // Execute whatever was set as callback passing it the serverTime
        callback?.Invoke(Utilities.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(now));         
    }, null);
}
```

And now call it passing the Coroutine as a callback e.g. as lambda expression (so you don't have to pass on the `craftTime` value between the methods)

```
public void StartCraft(double craftTime)
{
    playFab.GetServerTime(
        serverTime =>
        {
            double endTime = serverTime + craftTime;   
            StartCrafting(craftTime);
        }
    );
}
```

---

Alternatively if you prefer to have a method instead of the lambda you would have to pass on also the `craftTime` value between the methods and back to the callback

```
public void GetServerTime(double craftTime, Action<double, double> callback)
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetTime(new GetTimeRequest(), (GetTimeResult result) =>
    {          
        DateTime now = result.Time.AddHours(1); // GMT+1

        // Execute whatever was set as callback passing it the craftTime and serverTime
        callback?.Invoke(craftTime, Utilities.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(now));         
    }, null);
}
```

And now call it passing the Coroutine as a callback using a method passing on also the `craftTime` in order to have it in the callback as well

```
public void StartCraft(double craftTime)
{
    playFab.GetServerTime(craftTime, OnServerTimeReceived);
}

private void OnServerTimeReceived(double craftTime, double serverTime)
{
    double endTime = serverTime + craftTime;   
    StartCrafting(craftTime);
}
```

---

Or ofcause you could have a mix between the two and use a lambda expression to call the method

```
public void GetServerTime(Action<double> callback)
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetTime(new GetTimeRequest(), (GetTimeResult result) =>
    {          
        DateTime now = result.Time.AddHours(1); // GMT+1

        // Execute whatever was set as callback passing it the serverTime
        callback?.Invoke(Utilities.ConvertToUnixTimestamp(now));         
    }, null);
}
```

and

```
public void StartCraft(double craftTime)
{
    playFab.GetServerTime(
        serverTime =>
        {
            OnServerTimeReceived(craftTime, serverTime);
        }
    );
}

private void OnServerTimeReceived(double craftTime, double serverTime)
{
    double endTime = serverTime + craftTime;   
    StartCrafting(craftTime);
}
```

---

Note that if `StartCrafting` is really a Coroutine you can not call it like a method

```
StartCrafting(craftTime);
```

it has to be started instead as

```
StartCoroutine(StartCrafting(craftTime));
```

I assumed you are using it correctly and `StartCrafting` was a `void` that starts a Coroutine.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm. I will read more about this lambda expresion, looks like its a very useful resource.

Comment: at the beginning maybe a bit difficult to read but once you get used to them they are really handy sometimes. Please feel free to accept the answer if it helped you ;)